# Stopping Spark Streaming After process first hdfs streaming file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am running application by this command
./spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0 --class com.mmi.process.app.StartApp ./SparkFileStreaming.jar

But it stop automatically after process hdfs file. Please help why it is happening.

My Code is Below

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyWordCount");
sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.receiver.whiteAheadLog.enable", "true");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(60));
streamingContext.checkpoint("hdfs://Mongo1:9000/probeAnalysis/checkpoint");
String filePath = "hdfs://Master:9000/mmi_traffic/listenerTransaction/2020/*/*/*/";
JavaDStream<String> dStream = streamingContext.textFileStream(filePath).cache();
dStream.foreachRDD((rdd) -> {
    
    try {
        
        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long total = rdd.count();
        
        if(total > 0) {
            
            String filePath1 = Utils.getFilePath(rdd);
                        
            SparkSession sparkSession = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance();
            
            Dataset<Row> jsonDataset = sparkSession.read().json(path.toString()).cache();
            jsonDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("mmi_probes");
            Dataset<Row> probAnalysisData = sparkSession.sql("select sourceId, areaCode, vehicleType, "
                + "count(distinct deviceId) as totalDevices, "
                + "sum(valid+duplicate+history+future) as total, sum(valid) as valid, "
                + "sum(duplicate) as duplicate, sum(history) as history, sum(future) as future, "
                + "sum(count_0_2) as 0_2, sum(count_2_5) as 2_5, sum(count_5_10) as 5_10, "
                + "sum(count_10_15) as 10_15"
                + " from mmi_probes group by sourceId, areaCode, vehicleType");
                        
            MongoSpark.write(probAnalysisData)
            .option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://Mongo-server:27017/mmi_traffic.mmi_test_all")
            .mode("append")
            .save();
                    
            sparkSession.close();
            
        }
        
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
});

streamingContext.start();
streamingContext.awaitTermination();
streamingContext.close();
```

Comment: you cannout use sparkSession inside transformations ... you can have sparkSession object available in driver ... you need to rethink about the implementation and change code accordingly

Comment: Thank you so much. I did as you suggested. Now its working fine.